# Catching PHP bracket style elements with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a legacy PHP application which uses brackets in it's naming of form elements e.g.

```
<select name="samplegroup[776]" id="samplegroup[776]">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected >2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select name="samplegroup[883]" id="samplegroup[883]">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected >2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

How can I match selects which have `samplegroup` followed by a number in brackets with jQuery? E.g. `$("what_do_i_write_here")`?

Comment: You can't have `[` or `]` characters in ids. You need to fix that first.

Comment: Modern PHP applications still use brackets in names (and not IDs).

Comment: @David Dorward I think that depends on the doctype. I'm pretty sure HTML5 allows for most characters in an `id` or a `class`.

Comment: Let's not muddy the waters by mentioning `name` or `class`. Yes, HTML 5 allows for more characters than HTML 4. However, it is draft, and sticking to the values allowed in HTML 4 is good for compatibility reasons.

Comment: @David Dorward Wow, you've just upset a lot of people (inc. W3C) who are desperately trying to convince the developer community that HTML5 is good to go. :) All browsers as far back as IE6 will support the HTML5 doctype, which would resolve any compliance/standards issues. There isn't a compatibility issue as long as you're using HTML4/XHTML1 elements. Also, who mentioned `name`?

Comment: I don't have data on support for non-HTML 4 ids in browsers to hand. The HTML 5 doctype will trigger standards mode in almost all browsers that have a standards mode (I think I read somewhere that it won't in Netscape 6, but I don't care about that browser), but standards mode does not resolve every compatibility issue. It just means browsers do best efforts. `name` was mentioned by someone who has since deleted their comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`attributeStartsWith`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector:

```
$('select[name^="samplegroup"]')
```

It probably doesn't matter that this is ignoring the number in square brackets part, unless you happen to also have other `select` elements that have a `name` starting with `samplegroup`.

http://jsfiddle.net/PbSVY/

Comment: Many times it does matter that you're ignoring the number in the brackets -- if you're dynamically adding new form elements to the DOM (often the case when making an editing interface for multiple "child records")

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape brackets with `\\` in a jQuery selector.

Beside that, you can use `^=` sequence to tell jQuery (Sizzle) that the attribute you are looking for should *start* with the given string.

```
$('select[name^="samplegroup\\["]').doSomething();
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDrfK/1/

Answer (score 2):

This works and is cleaner than using the name.

```
$("#samplegroup\\[883\\]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify the selects to

```
<select name="samplegroup[776]" id="samplegroup_776">
```

and then

```
$("select.samplegroup_776"). //...
```

Or do you need the brackets in the ID? I understand the name tags but I don't think ID should be named like that.